# What is the best array-type choice for me?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, maps

I'm pretty new to coding so I am confused how I should approach this problem perfomance-wise.

In my programm I have 255 users who can store elements to their own unique array. I don't expect users to put more than 10 elements in each array, I also don't expect a big number of users but users can have any ID between (0-255).
Array iteration will happen about **60\second**. Each iteration will look into each sub-array(userID) and check some values from elements.

Not each of these users will have their own elements so during runtime it can be:

```
MyArr[0][0] // element 0 for User ID::0
MyArr[0][1] // element 1 for User ID::0
MyArr[50][0] // element 0 for User ID::50
MyArr[100][0] // element 0 for User ID::100
```

Each element will have their unique name.(as char). **So typical request will be::**

User(ID::0) calling function which would return value "Val" from element named "a".
I have userID and requested element name. First I'll have to get UserID sub array, then I'll have to iterate through the elements comparing name and return value to user.

So I don't know what array type should  I use.

1. If I use Vectors - their index is always in order. So I have to create Vector array of 255 and iterate through it 60\second even if 95% of arrays are empty.
2. If I use Maps - it is said maps are generally slower for little number of elements. But I can use this if maps are okay:

```
  map <string, Element> ElementsArray; // sub array with names::elements
  map <int, ElementsArray> MainArray; //  array with sub arrays
```

3. I can use just one array(Vector, for instance or simple C++ array) and store userID in the element itself. When user requests value - I will iterate through **all** elements, checking for UserID and getting value from the element.

What approach would be better in my case?(perfomance-wise)

Comment: define "better", faster? less memory? simpler code? I'd always go for the simplest code, make sure everything is well enough abstracted that you can change the data structures later if the performance is insufficent

Comment: better perfomance-wise (edited)

Comment: try each and see which works best, at your stated rate of 15,300 iterations per second giving 65 microseconds per iteration. I imagine all 3 options will be plenty fast enough so use the one that makes the simplest code

Comment: "I don't expect users to put more than 10 elements in each array, I also don't expect a big number of users but users can have any ID between (0-255)" Code in future tense, you should expect the number of elements to exceed 10 and the number of users to grow over 255. I would code it using map and profile it, unless you can measure a bottleneck, it is the way to go, the code is easier to read and it will cope transparently with more users.